# Considering a software fellowship. Is there a way I can make it not seem like job hopping?

Tags: resume, job-hopping

I'm a year into my first job out of university. I wasn't really picky about the work as the salary was a lot better than my other offers. However, there is no future in this job. There is only one spot above me and it was just filled by my current boss. I basically have no meaningful oversight of my work as my boss is too busy being another software engineer, so I have no idea if I am learning anything meaningful or just outputting trash. I am in a government department which, depending on how work from home goes in becoming permanent, may be far less relevant going forward. I am basically a code monkey being handed tickets, which is fine, but doesn't have a lot of future or growth potential.

I am thinking of taking a software fellowship for one year. It comes with a 20% pay raise, the work is far more interesting, and I would not be a code monkey. That fellowship would begin in December, giving me 15 months in my first job. The fellowship would last one year, taking me to the next December.

My main concern is that I would seem like a job hopper, even though the fellowship has a defined time for expiration so I would not be quitting it one year later. Is there any way to easily indicate that on my resume to avoid the job hopping problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't a govt job have growth potential? You can make a whole lucrative career in govt without much effort.

Comment: @Kilisi in government in general, yes. In that department, no, as there are 7 developers. My other option beyond this fellowship is a job with the feds across the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your resume, indicate that the position is a fellowship. Everyone knows that a fellowship lasts for a fixed amount of time and no one will think of you as a job hopper because you did one. If your job title has the word fellow in it, just leave it at that. If it doesn’t and your title is simply Software Developer (for example), just put “fellow” or “fellowship” in parentheses after the official title.

Comment: Yep, the title is Software Development Fellow. Thanks.